# Select query in azure adf pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

How to pass the select query in azure adf pipeline by fetching data from a file stored in azure blob.

For Ex :  my file(test) in blob is having a single value

in my adf pipeline in select query , we shd fetch the value from the table.

Sqlquery:"Select * from emp where id = (need to fetch the value from test)"

is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NB This answer refers to v1 of Azure Data Factory (ADF)**

v2 supports setting variables via the [Set Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-set-variable-activity) activity.

Re v1,
I do not think this is possible directly within the pipeline as Azure Data Factory does not really support variables in that way.  One other way of doing this would be to load the file from the blob into the same database where your other query is run, create a stored proc which joins the two, then call the stored proc using the [Stored Proc Activity](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/data-factory-stored-proc-activity/), eg:

```
SELECT * 
FROM emp 
WHERE id = ( SELECT id FROM yourBlobStagingTable );
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: This is a bit misleading, as getting a value out of a blob and then using it in a query is a core feature of Azure ADF.

Comment: Hi @Cninroh, I can understand your point but just by way of explanation this post applies to v1 of ADF which as at the time of the post, September 2016 was the current version.  v1 was quite limited and did not support variables in the way v2 does.  You can see the link I've supplied points to the v1 Stored Proc activity.  v2 which does have this ability, didn't GA until June 2018.  I'd be happy for you to update the post with a clarification on versions and rescind your downvote?

Comment: Hi @wBob, I actually did not realize the answer referred to v1 of ADF. I will adjust my answer accordingly and fix the vote as soon as it unlocks. In order for me to do so, could you please edit the question (maybe specify this is v1), as otherwise the vote is locked. Thanks for reaching out and for explaining the details!

Comment: Hi @Cninroh, I've updated my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The original answer addresses the v1 of ADF, where this functionality was not possible at a time.

As of v2 (GA June 2018) of ADF, it is now possible to pass parameters in the way demonstrated below. So the following pipeline definition would nowadays makes this possible.

What you want is Lookup getting a value from blob storage. You can then use it as a parameter in query using @concat string function. How to get the right value out of blob is up to your design. You can either use Lookup or Metadata for that.

Here is an example pipeline.

```
{
"name": "pipeline1",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "get_variable_from_file",
            "type": "Lookup",
            "dependsOn": [],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                        "recursive": true,
                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings",
                        "skipLineCount": 1
                    }
                },
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "blob_storage",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "firstRowOnly": true
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "use_variable_in_query",
            "type": "Copy",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "get_variable_from_file",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "AzurePostgreSqlSource",
                    "query": {
                        "value": "@concat('select * from schema.emp where id=',activity('get_variable_from_file').output)",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                },
                "enableStaging": false
            },
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "referenceName": "postgres_database",
                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                    "parameters": {
                        "table_name": "emp"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "annotations": []
}
```

}